# Convert timestamp to millisecond

Tags: android, type-conversion, timestamp

I'm working with timestamp format from Unix

1548230490

Is there anyway i can convert it to milliseconds in KOTLIN

Result : 1548230490308

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(YOUR TIMESTAMP VALUE)));
txtDate.setText(dateString);
```

Comment: i mean this is what i get from API 

1548230490
and how can i convert it to timestamp millisecond

Comment: @little_Friend check my answer

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of the date. If it is a date object containing millis information than you can, otherwise, if it is already a number (long for instance) than you have lost the millis information and can not recover it.

Comment: Exactly, if you're receiving timestamp in seconds, you can not recover the millis. think about it, you want to work with info that you simply does not have. The only thing that you can do it a simply *1000